# Sending and retrieving data from Messenger Webview and Botframework V4

Tags: c#, webview, botframework, messenger

I am planning to make a form UI for botframework v4 using Webview like this one. How can i receive values from the Webview back to c# bot framework? Also a way for bot to know if the user close the webview. And also if needed how can i send a value from C# to the webview?

[image]

And also what is the best or easiest way to host that html page? Thank you.

Comment: I'm still looking into the C# implementation, but in Node, if you encode the conversation reference in the URL's parameters, you can add the values to the form submission. Then you can create another REST API Endpoint in the project where you can submit the form. There you can reconstruct the conversation reference and send a proactive message to the user after they've submitted the form. In C#, I think you may have to add some web page scaffolding to create this behavior.

Comment: I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the [Proactive Messages Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). To begin, you will need to create a submit controller that is similar to the notify controller in the sample. Then you can store all of the conversation references by the conversation id on the bot side - there is a simplified example on how to do this in the sample.

Next, encode the conversation id as a URL parameter for your Messenger WebView. When the user submits the form, you can add the conversation id to the request and submit the data to the `api/submit` endpoint you created. Once you receive the request, look up the conversation reference with the id, and process the data and proactively message the user accordingly.

In terms of notifying your bot when the user closes the WebView, you can follow a similar approach and send an HTTP request to a controller when the `unload` event is triggered by the user navigating away from the WebView. For more details, take a look at the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event).

Hope this helps!